# How to position a table in R markdown on the left when using datatable()

Tags: datatable, r-markdown, position, alignment, dt

I am using the DT package and the function datatable() to display tables in a HTML output with R markdown. I have some tables that don't have very many columns, and therefore don't take up the full width of the page. By default, the tables postion themselves in the centre of the screen, how do I change this so they position on the left?

I am looking for somethign similar to the kable function:

`kable_styling(position  = "left")`

I can't find anything in the DT package that will do this.

Here's an example of a table i've tried to display:

```
my_table <- datatable(head(cars), rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = "rt"P)

my_table
```

No matter what options I use in datatable() I don't seem to be able to change the width, or get it positioned on the left. In the output I just keep getting a very wide table with lots of empty white space.

I'd like the final table to be narrower overall, and the columns an apropriate width for the content.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? A quick and dirty way would be to add a css class to your rmarkdown chunk and then style it to be positioned left. Check out this for more info [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I’ve not found a way of doing this with the datatable() function (or related functions) themselves, but you can achieve the desired result with html code either side of the data chunk.

````
<div style="width: 50%; float: left;">

```{r}
my_table <- datatable(head(cars), rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = "rt"P)
my_table
```

</div>
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
````

The 2nd div line setting the width back the 100% was necessary in my example, as it tried to fit some text next to the table that was previously below it, which did not look good. This ensures anything in the next section takes up the full page, and doesn’t wrap around what’s above. This many not be necessary for other examples.